# GitLab CI/CD Pipeline can't find GCC when building Debian package

Tags: linux, docker, gcc, gitlab, debian

**TL;DR - Why can't this pipeline find `gcc`?**

In the following pipeline, the job is failing because it cannot find `gcc` in the `PATH`.
This is using the official GCC docker image. I've also used this workflow for another project.

```yaml
image: gcc

variables:
  DEBVER: "1"
  VERSION: "0.0.1-alpha"
  JSON_PARSER_MIRROR: "https://gitlab.com/oxr463/json-parser/-/jobs/484303930/artifacts/raw"

deb:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - apt update && apt install -y debhelper devscripts libpam0g-dev
    - curl -O "${JSON_PARSER_MIRROR}/libjsonparser1.1_1.1.0-1_amd64.deb"
    - curl -O "${JSON_PARSER_MIRROR}/libjsonparser-dev_1.1.0-1_amd64.deb"
    - dpkg -i libjsonparser1.1_1.1.0-1_amd64.deb
    - dpkg -i libjsonparser-dev_1.1.0-1_amd64.deb
    - mkdir -p build
  script:
    - which gcc
    - export PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/bin"
    - tar cvzf "../pam-oauth2_${VERSION}.orig.tar.gz" --exclude='.git*' --exclude='*.deb' .
    - mv ../*.orig.tar.gz .
    - tar -xf *.orig.tar.gz -C build/
    - cd build
    - debuild -us -uc -d -i'(.*)'
  after_script:
    - rm -rf build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "*.deb"
```

Source: https://gitlab.com/oxr463/pam_oauth2/-/blob/debian-fix/.gitlab-ci.yml

```sh
$ debuild -us -uc -d -i'(.*)'
dpkg-architecture: warning: cannot determine CC system type, falling back to default (native compilation)
 dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -ui -d -i(.*)
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source package pam-oauth2
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source version 0.0.1-alpha-1
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source distribution UNRELEASED
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source changed by Lucas Ramage <ramage.lucas@protonmail.com>
dpkg-architecture: warning: cannot determine CC system type, falling back to default (native compilation)
 dpkg-source -i(.*) --before-build .
dpkg-buildpackage: info: host architecture amd64
 debian/rules clean
dh clean
   dh_auto_clean
    make -j1 clean
make[1]: Entering directory '/builds/oxr463/pam_oauth2/build'
rm *.o *.so pam_test pam_oauth2
rm: cannot remove '*.o': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '*.so': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'pam_test': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'pam_oauth2': No such file or directory
make[1]: [Makefile:43: clean] Error 1 (ignored)
make[1]: Leaving directory '/builds/oxr463/pam_oauth2/build'
   dh_clean
 dpkg-source -i(.*) -b .
dpkg-source: info: using source format '3.0 (quilt)'
dpkg-source: info: building pam-oauth2 using existing ./pam-oauth2_0.0.1-alpha.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: building pam-oauth2 in pam-oauth2_0.0.1-alpha-1.debian.tar.xz
dpkg-source: info: building pam-oauth2 in pam-oauth2_0.0.1-alpha-1.dsc
 debian/rules build
make: 'build' is up to date.
 debian/rules binary
dh binary
   dh_update_autotools_config
   debian/rules override_dh_auto_configure
make[1]: Entering directory '/builds/oxr463/pam_oauth2/build'
dh_auto_configure -- --with-pam-dir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security
make[1]: Leaving directory '/builds/oxr463/pam_oauth2/build'
   dh_auto_build
    make -j1
make[1]: Entering directory '/builds/oxr463/pam_oauth2/build'
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/builds/oxr463/pam_oauth2/build=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Werror -fPIC -I/system/apps/pam/latest/include -I/system/apps/curl/latest/include -I/system/apps/json-parser/latest/include -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -c -o pam_oauth2_core.o pam_oauth2_core.c
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
make[1]: *** [<builtin>: pam_oauth2_core.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/builds/oxr463/pam_oauth2/build'
dh_auto_build: make -j1 returned exit code 2
make: *** [debian/rules:6: binary] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1182:
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -ui -d -i(.*) failed
```

Source: https://gitlab.com/oxr463/pam_oauth2/-/jobs/485171400

Reference:

- https://hub.docker.com/_/gcc
- https://gitlab.com/oxr463/json-parser/-/blob/debian/.gitlab-ci.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `debuild` man page says (in the ENVIRONMENTAL VARIABLES section):

> As environment variables can affect the building of a package, often
>   unintentionally, debuild sanitises the environment by removing all
>   environment variables except for TERM, HOME, LOGNAME, GNUPGHOME,
>   PGPPATH, GPG_AGENT_INFO, FAKEROOTKEY, DEB_*, the ( C, CPP, CXX, LD and
>   F) FLAGS variables and their _APPEND counterparts and the locale
>   variables LANG and LC_*. TERM is set to `dumb' if it is unset, and
>   PATH is set to "/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11".

Reference:
https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/devscripts/debuild.1.en.html

Use `debuild --prepend-path=/usr/local/bin ...`